# Match simultaneous tags in Java String

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a Java program where there is some data that has to be pulled from a String (in practice this is html).

My code is as follows:

```
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("xrefInternal")) {
                    String ftnNum = line.replaceAll("(.*)(<sup>)([0-9]+)(</sup>)(.*)", "$3");
                    String ftnRefNum = line.replaceAll("(.*)(<span class=\"xrefInternal\" id=\"fo)([0-9]+)(\")(.*)", "$3");
                    System.out.println(ftnRefNum + "\t" + ftnNum);
                }
            }
```

While working on this I came across 2 cases in my File.

**Case 1**

```
<p class="paraNoIndent1" style="text-indent: 0%;">texy<span class="xrefInternal" id="fo249"><a href="abc.html#fo_249"><sup>2</sup></a></span> Tewxt.<span class="xrefInternal" id="fo250"><a href="abc.html#fo_250"><sup>3</sup></a></span> text</p>
```

**Case 2**

```
<p class="paraNoIndent1" style="text-indent: 0%;">Text.<span class="xrefInternal" id="fo248"><a href="abc.html#fo_248"><sup>1</sup></a></span></p>
```

`Case 1` doesn't print anything. It is skipped (I think due to trying to fetch two data elements in the same paramater).

`Case 2` prints the result as expected as below

```
248 1
```

Here is working [Regex Fiddle](http://regexr.com/3d411)

Please let me know how rework the code so that `Case 1` will function like `Case 2`

Thanks

Comment: Mandatory links: (general) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags (more specific) http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1393766.

Comment: This is why one does not use regex to parse XML or HTML.  XML and HTML are not regular languages and are not generally parseable with regex, except in very limited cases.  Use a real HTML or XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

## The behavior you describe is not a result of the regex, and cannot be reproduced with the code provided.

(I will update/delete this if/when more information is provided. It's too long for a comment, and will help the flag people.)

I get (text represents example number):

```
250   one   3
248   two   1
```

When I run this:

```
 String example1="<p class=\"paraNoIndent1\" style=\"text-indent: 0%;\">texy<span class=\"xrefInternal\" id=\"fo249\"><a href=\"abc.html#fo_249\"><sup>2</sup></a></span> Tewxt.<span class=\"xrefInternal\" id=\"fo250\"><a href=\"abc.html#fo_250\"><sup>3</sup></a></span> text</p>";


 String ftnNum = example1.replaceAll("(.*)(<sup>)([0-9]+)(</sup>)(.*)", "$3");
 String ftnRefNum = example1.replaceAll("(.*)(<span class=\"xrefInternal\" id=\"fo)([0-9]+)(\")(.*)", "$3");
 System.out.println(ftnRefNum + "   one   " + ftnNum);

 String example2="<p class=\"paraNoIndent1\" style=\"text-indent: 0%;\">Text.<span class=\"xrefInternal\" id=\"fo248\"><a href=\"abc.html#fo_248\"><sup>1</sup></a></span></p>";
 String ftnNum2 = example2.replaceAll("(.*)(<sup>)([0-9]+)(</sup>)(.*)", "$3");
 String ftnRefNum2 = example2.replaceAll("(.*)(<span class=\"xrefInternal\" id=\"fo)([0-9]+)(\")(.*)", "$3");

 System.out.println(ftnRefNum2 + "   two   " + ftnNum2);
```